# Divs coming down instead of coming in line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a web page as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bnkckqkd/). But `divs` are coming down as shown. I want thise divs to come in straight line. Here is `css` code:

```
#header #menu #plc #register{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 1% 0 0 0;
    background-color: #02080f;
    width: 12%;
}
#header #menu #plc #register img{
    width: 15.5%;
    margin-left: 7%;
}
#register img, #register div{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#register{ white-space: nowrap;}
#register div{
    padding: 0 0 0 5%;
}
#header #menu #plc #registerOne {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D: I've edited my question, please check it

Comment: Part of the issue, I suspect, is that you are reusing IDs. You can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`inline-block`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) so that they are placed in a single line. Please try to follow [**Frontend Guidelines**](https://github.com/bendc/frontend-guidelines/) for writing your HTML/CSS.

```
#register {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/bnkckqkd/2/)

Comment: Okay, sure... I'll follow those guideline. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, Ajay! :)